# best practice invoking webservices

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm doing a school project where we are supposed to tap into an existing database using web services. I'm trying to figure out what best practice is when calling a web service from back end. I've been working with Servlets before and I know them pretty well.

This is my web service that front end uses and I need to know what the best practice is when calling an external web service within my application:

```
@GET
@Path("requestAccess")
public void getAccessToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    String clientId = "4_4inr3rkl04ys44kowwgoo0w4g8gow0s84cw0o0cg48kogsosc0";
    String clientSecret = "4cxgpduio8isgcc8oggsw8wkcokcksk8wc8cc088w4w40owg4s";
    String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/salesgoals/rest/oauth/requestAccess";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://.../oauth/v2/token?client_id="+clientId+"&client_secret="+clientSecret+"&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri="+redirectUrl+"&code="+code);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String strTemp = "";
        while(null != (strTemp = bufferedReader.readLine())){
            System.out.println(strTemp);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This returns me an access token and the results from the external web service are JSON objects and the url object with inputstreamReader is something temp. I used to see if I was successful receiving access token.

Now I need to use the access token to invoke external web services but I dont know what best practice is when it comes to calling it within the application. I'm used to HttpServletRequest/Response objects. As I said all the data is returned as json.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is 100% best practice, but take a look at
[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)

It is both client and server RESTful web services implementation.